# Why does VisualStudio 2019 occasionally produce the same errors for all C++ projects in solution

Tags: c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have a few VisualStudio solutions that occasionally produce the same three warnings for every included C++ project during a build. A sample from one project:

```
------ Build started: Project: SESAMgmtObj, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(39,5): warning MSB4211: The property "IntermediateOutputPath" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets (38,5)".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.BuildSteps.Targets(30,5): warning MSB4211: The property "DebugType" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.BuildSteps.Targets (29,5)".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(373,5): warning MSB4211: The property "CleanFile" is being set to a value for the first time, but it was already consumed at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets (38,5)".
```

If I kill all instance of VisualStudio then restart, the warnings no longer occur. Is this just a bug in VisualStudio? Am I doing something wrong?

I have only tested this with VisualStudio 2019 version 16.11.11.

Comment: I've not run into that kind of (mis)behavior in Visual Studio 2019.  It could be that your project is in some kind of "funny" state.  One suggestion to try (if you are so inclined) is to recreate the project from brand new, and then add the source files.

Comment: I moved to a new computer and did a fresh install of VS2019; the issue still occurs. @Eljay I haven't tried to recreate the projects though and I don't know if I will get the time.

Comment: That's what I'd expect to happen if the project file itself is damaged (in a "funny" state).